# replace a image button to show it was pressed

Tags: 2013, image

I am trying to show which button was pressed on an aspx form, based on the parameters passed from the previous load of the page.

sample of image button:

```
<a title="All" href="/MySite/My%20Queue.aspx"> 
    <img alt="All.jpg" src="/MySite/MyQueue/All.jpg" style="margin&#58;5px;" />
</a>
```

but I don't know how to put an if statement to load the image that it's there or a different one, based on the text in the http line.

Any ideas?

Thanks